# Find $k$ for $F_X(x) = k \operatorname{sech}^n(x)dx$

Tags: integration, statistics

A distribution is given by
$$F_X(x) = k \operatorname{sech}^n(x) , -\infty<x<\infty$$
Show that $k = \frac{\Gamma\{1/2(n+1)\}}{\Gamma(n/2)\Gamma(1/2)}, $

It looks to me that $k = \frac{1}{B(n/2, 1/2)}$ where $B(n/2, 1/2)$ is the beta distribution.

Taking the derivative of $\frac{\partial F_X(x)}{\partial x} = nk \operatorname{sech}^{n-1}(x) \cdot (-\tanh(x) \operatorname{sech}(x))dx = f_X(x)$

Then taking the integral at those limits
$$-kn\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\operatorname{sech}^{n}(x)\tanh(x)dx$$

However this integral is currently a little too tricky for my to compute with my tools - are their any simpler alternatives? Furthermore, when I plug this integral into wolfram, I cannot find a result that would give me the value of $k$ as above.

Comment: Are you sure that $\frac{\partial F_X(x)}{\partial x} = nk \operatorname{sech}^{n-1}(x)$ ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thanks for pointing that out, I updated it. Not sure what happened with my logical skills! I'll give this another go

Comment: I think you're confused about which function is used for what here. Your title equation makes no sense. When it loses $dx$ in the body, it specifies an $F_X$ that's not increasing, so must be a PDF (usually instead denoted $f_X$), not a CDF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I noted in a comment, $k\operatorname{sech}^nx$ should be the PDF, not the CDF. Substituting $e^x=\tan t$ and using the [Legendre duplication formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_theorem#Gamma_function%E2%80%93Legendre_formula),$$\begin{align}k^{-1}&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\frac{2e^{x}}{1+e^{2x}}\right)^{n}dx\\&=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}2^{n}\sin^{n-1}t\cos^{n-1}tdt\\&=2^{n-1}B\left(\tfrac{n}{2},\,\tfrac{n}{2}\right)\\&=\frac{\Gamma\left(\tfrac{n}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(\tfrac12\right)}{\Gamma\left(\tfrac{n+1}{2}\right)}.\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I've been reading through Kendalls Advanced Statistics and the old notations through my off. Identifying it by whether $dx$ is present or not has helped me.